# Which will get Priority between "github pages" and "directory kept at root" in case of name conflicts and why

Tags: html, git, github, github-pages

Say I have an index.html put on my username.github.io, which I can visit by the url, `http://username.github.io`

**Now consider 2 conflicting cases**

1. Say, I have a repository named `repo1` with gh-pages activated. So, it should be available at `http://username.github.io/repo1`
2. I also have put a folder named `repo1` with an index.html inside it, at the `username.github.io` location.

**Here's my question**

Now, if I visit from my browser the url `http://username.github.io/repo1` which one of 1 or 2 will be served? and more importantly **WHY** ?

Comment: Good question. I guess the folder at the root directory `username.github.io` will get priority, but I have never tested/done it.So, let's see what experts say :)

Comment: Sorry, just tested it, above comment is false. Just the opposite happens. See my partial answer.

Answer (score 3):

I tested it with my github repo `sumanbarick.github.io`.

**Finding:** Repository (github pages) will get priority in case of name conflict.

**Test 1: `http://sumanbarick.github.io/test/`**

1. First I made a repository name `test` with an index.html inside it. Created branch gh-pages. I tried the url `http://sumanbarick.github.io/test/` and I got the page index.html.
2. Then I created a folder named `test` and an index.html inside it in `sumanbarick.github.io` repo
3. I hit the url again. But still got he index.html from the repo

**Test 2: Does 1st defined gets the 1st priority?**

1. This time I made a folder named `test2` and an index.html inside it in `sumanbarick.github.io` repo. I tried the url `http://sumanbarick.github.io/test2/` and I got the page index.html from folder test2
2. But as soon as I created the repo `test2` with gh-pages, the result of the url favored the index page of the repo

So, this is a partial answer. And now we know,

**Q. Which one will get priority?**

A. The repo (Go to the above mentioned url and see for yourself).

**Q. Why?**

A. I am still curious about this **WHY** part. Let's see what others say.